# API search holds information in diferent locations. (Reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I am trying to search for a food item and display the amount of protein in the food using USDA's api. When I search for 'apple' and I console.log the results I get the following: [image]

So for me to access the protein I just needed the following code:

```
const protein = res['data']['foods']['0']['foodNutrients']['8']['value'];
this.setState({ protein })
```

The problem I ran into was when I searched for 'orange':

[image]

Protein was located in a different area than the code I had put and I got the following error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): res.data.foods[0].foodNutrients[8] is undefined
```

I understand why I got the error but I do not know how to setup a function or component to solve this issue. How do you get the same property (protein) for different searches of food items if the result shows up in a slightly different spot depending on the search?

Here is my full code so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios'




export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    protein: "",
    calories: "",
    caloriesName: "",
  }

  clickHandler = (event) => {


    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      const query = event.target.value;
      const API_KEY = '*********'
      axios.get(`https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${query}`)
        .then(res => {

//find protein
          const target = 'nutrientName'
          function filter(data, target){
            return data.filter(item => item[target])
      }
        var x = res['data']['foods']['0']['foodNutrients']
        const c = filter(x,target)
        console.log(c)

          console.log(res)

          const protein = res['data']['foods']['0']['foodNutrients']['8']['value'];
          this.setState({ protein })

          const calories = res['data']['foods']['0']['foodNutrients']['10']['value'];
          this.setState({ calories })

        })


    }
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.protein} </h1>
        <h1>{this.state.calories} </h1>
        <input onKeyDown={event => this.clickHandler(event)} />
      </div>
    )
  }


}
```

Comment: Did you try using [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)?

Comment: I read the link, How can I set that up with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a function that would iterate over the keys in the json object.

Take a look at
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

It could give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Write a method which will loop over the array of object and filter the item based on the provided data. Here we need to check key 'nutrition' is equal to 'protein'

```js
function filter(data, target,key){
  return data.filter(item =>  item[target] === key)
}
const target =  'nu'
const key = 'protein'
var x = [{ nu:'protein',value:10},{y:20},{z:10,nu:20}]

const c = filter(x,target,key)
console.log(c[0].value)
```

Comment: Do I put 'protein' for target, and I do not undserstand var  x  values.

Comment: target is protein and x is res['data']['foods']['0']['foodNutrients'].
It will return you a array -> result = [ {...} ]
to get value from result -> result[0].value

Comment: I edited my code with what I have, in the console I am getting an empty string with length 0

Comment: target is nutrientName and x is res['data']['foods']['0']['foodNutrients']. It will return you a array -> result = [ {...} ] to get value from result -> result[0].value

Done a correction.Here you need to check key value should be 'protein'

Comment: I changed it as you said, except not sure where to put protein now. In the console, I am getting an array of all 14 nutrientNames with what I just updated the code with.

Comment: Ah, I see you changed the code I didnt realize you said that, Now trying it this way I still get an empty array in console.log

Comment: I can see you are not comparing the code.
 data.filter(item =>  item[target] === 'protein')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219622/discussion-between-deepak-and-caleb).